# Почему помещение переменной %{count} на первое место в en.yml выдает 500 Internal Server Error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, i18n

Есть такой код (app/views/shared/_form_errors.html.haml):

```
%p= t('.errors', count: @user.errors.count)
```

Его суть - выводить сообщение о количестве ошибок, найденных при заполнении формы.

Есть файл config/locales/views/shared/en.yml, в нем такой код:

```
en:
  shared:
    form_errors:
      prohibited: stop
      errors:
        one: Seems like one error doesn't allow you to move on
        other: Seems like %{count} errors don't allow you to move on
```

Сейчас этот код работает. Но стоит мне только убрать в начале (строки `other:`) слова "Seems like" (то есть поместить переменную непосредственно в начало строки с переводом), как я получаю следующее:
[image: 500 Internal Server Error]
Окей, я действительно владелец приложения, сейчас почитаю логи.

> Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 138ms (ActiveRecord: 1.2ms)
>
> I18n::InvalidLocaleData (can not load translations from
>   /home/matt/workspace/www/rails/demo/config/locales/views/shared/en.yml:
>
> found character that cannot start any token while scanning for the
>   next token at line 7 column 16>):
>   app/controllers/account_controller.rb:54:in `update_password'

Почему такое происходит? Даже на RailsGuides авторы спокойно помещают переменную на первое место. А здесь крашится целое приложение. В чем дело?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оберни в двойные кавычки

```
other: "Seems like %{count} errors don't allow you to move on"
```

Comment: О-фи-геть. И всего-то надо было. Спасибо большое! приму ответ как правильный через 9 минут.